# C# Parse JSON Array Elements

Tags: c#, windows

I am working on a Windows 8 Store app in VS 2012 and new to C# and XAML.  Using the JsonArray to parse a Json feed how do I grab an element from an array within another array?

```
[

    {
        "item_id": 2270978,
        "item_title": "This is the title",
        "roles": [

            {
                "item_url": "http://www.blahblah.com/161089",
                "parent_url": "http://www.blahblah.com",
            },
            {
                "item_url": "http://www.blahblah.com/469888",
                "parent_url": "http://www.blahblah.com",
            }

        ],
    }
]
```

I thought another foreach would work within the original foreach but I get an error:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Windows.Data.Json.IJsonValue'

```
           foreach (var item in items)
            {
                JsonObject theItem = item.GetObject();
                FeedItem feedItem = new FeedItem();

                feedItem.PubDate = System.DateTime.Now;
                feedItem.Title = theItem["item_title"].GetString();
                feedItem.Author = "Me";
                feedItem.ItemId = (int)(theItem["item_id"].GetNumber());
                feedItem.Content = theItem["item_body"].GetString();
                feedItem.Link = new Uri(theItem["permalink_url"].GetString());

                var roles = theItem["roles"].GetArray();
/* TRIED LIKE THIS DOESN'T WORK
                foreach (var role in roles)
                {
                    feedItem.ContentUrl = new Uri(role["item_url"].GetString());
                }
*/
                feed.Items.Add(feedItem);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating over wrong variable. Should be:

```
            var roles = theItem["roles"].GetArray();
            foreach (var role in roles)
            {
                feedItem.ContentUrl = new Uri(role.GetObject()["item_url"].GetString());
            }
```

Also there is no `content_url` element in your input JSON string. Shouldn't it be `item_url` or `parent_url`?

Comment: Yes it is item_url, I had just changed it.

Comment: I changed the variables around I'll change them again to match my original code.  Thanks so much, you rock!